# C++ - is there a way to inherit some functions only once, while others multiple times in multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, chess

My problem is the following:

I am creating a chess game in C++, and there is a base class `Figure` that contains the functionality shared by all figures with a virtual function `checkMove` that is redefined individually for each figure (as, naturally, each figure moves under different rules). The chess board is a two dimensional array of pointers to `Figure`s (empty squares are simply null pointers).

The thing is, I would like to have the `Queen` inherit the `Rook` and `Bishop`, as it is a mix of both for all intents and purposes, instead of writing its own needlessly long `checkMove` override.

And then comes my problem: in the base `Figure` class, there are the fundamental functions of defining which character the figure will be represented by in the console, which team it belongs to, etc. I would like the queen to only inherit one instance of these functions.

However, I would like the queen to inherit the `checkMove` function twice - once from the `Rook`, and once from the `Bishop`, so as to simply call both in its own `checkMove` version..

I tried some solutions, also played around with the `Rook` and `Bishop` inheriting the `Figure` class virtually, however I can't seem to put the pieces together. I am new to the concept of polymorphism so I can't find proper logic to implement that functionality. What would be a good approach?

Comment: "I would like to have the Queen inherit the Rook and Bishop" **Don't**. A queen is not a rook. A queen is not a bishop. Don't abuse inheritance. And keep it simple. Also, learn to use some whitespace to help us read your questions.

Comment: A good read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID (especially the L part ;)

Comment: You can create utility functions to check for horizontal and diagonal moves and call them as needed to reuse the code without resorting to inheritance.

Comment: "If it quacks like a duck, moves like a duck, but needs batteries, you probably have the wrong abstraction." https://vegibit.com/liskov-substitution-principle/

Comment: once I was made to believe that inheritance is the right hammer for every nail, it was a great relief when I realized that actually it is not. The simple truth is: If you want to inherit a Queen from a Rook, then you are doing something wrong. Forget about inheritane completely for a moment and rethink your design

Answer (score 2):

**A Queen is not a Rook.**

I would steer (far) away from inheritance here - the only reuse is only for the queen really.

A better design here would be something like the following (**pseudocode**):

```
struct Queen {
  ValidMoves canMove(GameState state) {
    ValidMoves res;
    res.insert( canMoveAsRook(state) );
    res.insert( canMoveAsBishop(state) );
    return res;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

But it's not directly obvious. You don't inherit `Queen` from `Rook` and `Bishop`. Instead, you introduce a specific `Move` base class. Now `QueenMove` can inherit from `RookMove` and `BishopMove`. The `Queen` piece simply is a `Piece` type, whose constructor sets `Piece::move` (a `unique_ptr<Move>`) to `QueenMove`.

Comment: AKA the Strategy pattern :)

Comment: I'd say that QueenMove inheriths from Move and _has a_ collection (vector?) of Move instances, containing a RookMove and a BishopMove (or simply two members of the two types) To check for a valid move, it asks to both the Moves instances, returning true if one of the two returns true. Dealing with multiple inheritance make things more complicated here, IMHO

Comment: I wouldn't relate `QueenMove` and `RookMove`.    A rook can participate in castling.  A queen cannot.

Comment: @GianPaolo: Given that it's specfically a QueenMove, why use a collection? It can have 2 named members. But base classes or named members are pretty much the same here, both are sub-objects.

Comment: @Peter: True, but castling is neither a `KingMove` nor a `RookMove`. It has a completely unique set of rules (e.g. not just determined by the position of the pieces, and the only move where two pieces move in one ply)

Comment: @MSalters _But base classes or named members are pretty much the same here_ With inheritance you are saying that everytime you need a Rook (or Bishop)Move, you can use a QueenMove. That's smells to me. I prefer composition over inheritance here

Comment: @GianPaolo: In some contexts, that actually would make sense. To answer the question, "which piece could move to this field", a queen can if either a rook or a bishop can.